# AngularJS NG-Repeat JSON

Tags: angularjs

I apologize for this simple question. I've been scouring other questions and still can't get it to work.

I have a function returning some key/value pairs

```
function(data){
    console.log(data.message);
}
```

Returns...

```
Object {name: "mpierce486", body: "asfsf", time: "1 second ago"}
```

I have the following when not logging to console...

```
$scope.message = data.message
```

Lastly, here's the markup. I'm using a Laravel app so I'm escaping the {{ with @. Nothing shows up and I know it's a simple mistake. Please assist! Thanks!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="messageCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in message" class="main-user-post">
      <h1>@{{ x.body }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do an `ng-repeat` on an object. Since it's already an object, not an array, you can access it directly, without ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="messageCtrl">
    <div class="main-user-post">
      <h1>@{{ message.body }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You *can* do a repeat on an object, via `ng-repeat="(key, val) in object"` - but I don't think OP wants that.

Answer (score 1):

your message variable is an object, not an array. So in your iteration, x will take the value of each object properties (body, name, time).

So either use a different approach, or transform your message to an array:

```
 $scope.message = [data.message];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through object properties with angular like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="messageCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in message" class="main-user-post">
      <h1>@{{value}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object array as below.
JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/L7k6g7ua/ for reference w.r.t AngularJs  -

Hope this helps!

```
   <body ng-app="SampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="messageCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="m in message" class="main-user-post">
      <h1>{{m.body}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

    var sampleApp = angular.module("SampleApp", []);
    sampleApp.controller('messageCtrl', function($scope) {
      var myObject = {
        name: "mpierce486",
        body: "asfsf",
        time: "1 second ago"
      };

      var myArray = [];
      myArray.push(myObject);
      $scope.message = myArray;
    });
```